# USB-C to HDMI adapter that works with Ubuntu?

Tags: hardware, hdmi, adapter, usb-c

Do they exist?

If so, does anybody have a link?

Just bought two from eBay and neither works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, according to the [help center](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), hardware recommendation questions should be avoided in Ask Ubuntu, thus this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 6):

I just got a CHOETECH USB-C to HDMI adapter.  Plugged it into a Lenovo X270 laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 and it just worked.  Zero configuration required.

Answer (score 3):

I did research last year for the most popular Thunderbolt to HDMI adapter I could find. Like some users my first adapter did not plug in tightly and signal could shutoff on it's own. The Vendor actually reached out to me before I could complain with a customer satisfaction survey. I told them the problem and a new one arrived in a few days and I'm still using it.

[CHOETECH Type C to HDMI Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071DGKBYP):

[image]

Comment: BTW - you're using Ubuntu? Which DE? Does it create an interface that appears in something like Arandr?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 with Unity interface. Xrandr name is `DP-1-1` but it may vary by machine. Skylake 6700HQ with 40 gbs PCH Thunderbolt.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure that what I bought indeed wasn't working as expected. No additional interface appeared in xrandr.

Comment: When you buy these adapters the fine print specifies what operating systems and hardware types are supported.

Answer (score 2):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm posting this as an answer.)

I can confirm that the choetech adapter seems to work. My model looks a bit different than the others linked in this thread (maybe because I'm in Germany), but it works fine as well. This is the model I purchased: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07F6WD1J7

I tried an ivanky usb c to hdmi cable first ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07NPHK6LR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NPHK6LR)), but it didn't work reliably. It took a long time (sometimes up to 3 minutes) until the display shows something again after waking up from standby.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Club 3D CAC-1504 USB-C to HDMI 2.0.

```
Laptop: Latitude 5580, i5 7440HQ, NVIDIA 940MX with Thunderbolt3 over USB-C.
Monitor: LG 32UD59-B, 32 inch, 4k@60Hz.
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1
```

Some laptops have DisplayPort over USB-C(Latitude 5590, i5 8250u, no discrete GPU) and the above adapter works with LG 32UD59-B.

Other laptops have USB-C only for data transfer(no DisplayPort, no Thunderbolt3) and the adapter will not work.

Answer (score 0):

bought this one on Amazon.es ( i live in Portugal )
and worked fine, plug and play!
I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B076HN8217/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1